# "SAP Connector for .NET": Generate proxies without Visual Studio 2003

Tags: .net, proxies, sap-dotnet-connector

Are there possibilities/ways to generate **"SAP Connector for .NET"-proxies** without Visual Studio 2003, so that they can be used in Visual Studio 2008 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be this place can help you:

http://www.dataxstream.com/2009/08/using-the-sap-net-connector-in-visual-studio-2008/

Or:

http://www.sdn.sap.com/irj/scn/go/portal/prtroot/docs/library/uuid/92333e6b-0b01-0010-9cbf-fecd62d6c895?QuickLink=index&overridelayout=true

Regards.

Comment: Any luck creating SAP proxy with Visual Studio 2010?

Answer (score 2):

You can use NC0 3.0

[SAP Connector for Microsoft .NET 3.0 released.](http://williamvanstrien.blogspot.com/2010/12/sap-connector-for-microsoft-net-30.html)
The NCo 3.0 can be downloaded from [SAP Service Marketplace](https://websmp209.sap-ag.de/~form/sapnet?_SHORTKEY=01100035870000719347&), including accompanying documentation.

Answer (score 1):

NCo 3.0 differs substantially from NCo 2.0:

With the .NET Connector 2.0, the NCo design time would generate a “proxy method”
for each ABAP function module you want to call, and one specific class for each
structure or table type that this function module is referencing. You had to create
objects from these structure/table classes and pass them into the proxy method
corresponding to the function module.
Now with the .NET Connector 3.0, there is no longer any kind of generated code.
Instead of one generated proxy method for each function module, there is one single
IRfcFunction class, whose Invoke() method dynamically executes every given
ABAP function module. And instead of a dedicated generated class for every
structure and table, there is one generic IRfcStructure class representing all
possible structures, and analogously one generic IRfcTable class for all tables. So
basically instead of hard-wiring everything statically at design time, NCo 3.0 now
handles everything dynamically at runtime. Another difference is that you no longer
need to create the objects for structures and tables yourself. You only create one
IRfcFunction object, and it internally takes care of all contained structures and
tables (using lazy initialization).